# Independence of permuted substrings

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, permutations, independence

[Disclaimer: Sorry for the bad title. I really don't know a better short description of the problem. Please comment if you have a better title in mind!]

I wonder how the following events are correlated. My intuition is they might be independent but somehow this feels too easy. it also feels like something others have already thought about, so maybe somebody has a clue?

**Informally:** given two different even bit strings (on an even number of bits). Acting on both bit strings with the same random permutation, how are the parities of the respective substrings on the first half of the bits correlated?

**Notation:** Let $n$ be an even integer throughout the post. We say a bit string $x=x_1x_2\dots x_n\in\{0,1\}^n$ has even parity (or *is an even bit string*) if
$$\sum_i x_i \bmod 2=0.$$
For $j<k$ denote by $x_j^k$ the substrting of $x$
$$x_j^k=x_jx_{j+1}\dots x_k.$$
Denote by $\bar{x}$ the string resulting from flipping all bits in $x$.
For a permutation $\sigma:[n]\rightarrow[n]$ denote by $\sigma(x)$ its action on the string labels
$$\sigma(x)=x_{\sigma(1)}x_{\sigma(2)}\dots x_{\sigma(n)}$$

**Question (Formally):**
Now, assume we are given uniform random access to permutations $\sigma$ (i.e. each permutation is drawn with probability $1/n!$), then for every even bit string $x$ define the event
$$E(x)=\{\sigma(x)_1^{n/2} \text{  is even}\}.$$
What are the correlations between events $E(x)$ and $E(y)$ assuming $x\neq y$ and $x\neq\bar{y}$ (depending on the pair $(x,y)$)?

As a starter it would be great to see if they independent?

Ideally, somebody knows a formula of the form
$$\mathbb{P}[E(x)\cap E(y)]= \mathbb{P}[E(x)]\mathbb{P}[E(y)](1+f(x,y))$$
for some function $f$ of $x$ and $y$.

Also, it would be a great help to see in a counter example that they are not independent (if they aren't)!

Comment: So how are we given the two bit strings? Also uniformly?

Comment: They are fixed. But arbitrary. No sampling of those. Only $x\neq y$ is assumed. So it’s a Great help if you can construct some x and y such that these events have a particular correlation.

Comment: Since we're not dealing with specific $x$ and $y$, if the events aren't independent, wouldn't the function in your last line be some function $f(\sigma)$ rather than $f(x,y)$. And to that point, when you say construct some $x,y$ such that these evens are correlated in some way, I think you mean to ask if there is some $\sigma$ such that events are correlated in some way.

Comment: Ah, O think I should write things out more explicitly. I will make some changes to the question then you see why f depends on x,y and not on sigma (btw as P is the probability over permutations sigma f cannot depend on sigma)